# Is this a probability measure on the cantor set?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, fractals, cantor-set

$c$ is the Cantor function, $C$ the Cantor set, and $\rho$ the Lebesgue measure

We consider $\mu$ as $\mu(A) = \rho(c(A \cap C))$ for each each element of the tribute

Is $\mu$ currently defining probability measure on the Cantor set (means the support of $\mu$ is C) ?

I have issue showing the sigma-additivity...

Comment: We have to show that c( U A_i ) = U c(A_i) and here I dont know how to process, any idea or result on the cantor function can help

Comment: the equality (⋃⋂)=⋃(⋂) is evident, the problem is to show that (⋂) are two by two disjoint, and that comes from the fact that c is injective on the Cantor set

Comment: $c$ is not injective in the Cantor set. $c(1/3) =c(2/3)$.

Comment: So I don't see why $\mu$ is sigma-addtitive

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: I upvoted and checked the answer, nice ideas thank you

Comment: Thanks. Please, could you make sure you upvoted. It is not showing upvoted.  To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question.

Comment: I did it but I got the following message : "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Please, try again. I think it will work now.

Comment: yes, added now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to define $\mu$ on the Borel (or Lebesgue) $\sigma$-algebra in $\Bbb R$.

Let $c$ be the Cantor function, $C$ the Cantor set, and $\rho$ the Lebesgue measure. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $\Bbb R$.

Let $\mu(A) = \rho(c(A \cap C))$ for each each element $A \in \mathcal{B}$.

First, we must prove that  $\mu$ is well-defined. It means, we must prove that if $A \subseteq \Bbb R$ is Borel measurable then $c(A\cap C)$ is Borel (or Lebesgue) measurable, so we can have $\rho(c(A \cap C))$.

Let $\Sigma =\{A \subseteq \Bbb R: \exists E \subseteq [0,1] \textrm{ Borel measurable, such that } A\cap C=c^{-1}(E) \}$. It is easy to prove that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that, since $c$ is monotone, every open interval is in $\Sigma$. So $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \Sigma$.  So, if $A \subseteq \Bbb R$ is Borel measurable, there is $E$ Borel measurable such that $A\cap C=c^{-1}(E)$, so, since $c: C \rightarrow [0,1]$ is surjective, we have that $c(A\cap C)=E$ is Borel measurable. So $\mu$ is well-defined.

Let us now prove $\mu$ is a measure. We have
$$\mu(\emptyset) = \rho(c(\emptyset \cap C)) =\rho(c(\emptyset )) = \rho(\emptyset) =0$$

Now, let $\Gamma =\{ y\in [0,1] : \exists a,b \in C, a\neq b \textrm{ and } y=c(a)=c(b)\}  $. It is easy to prove that $\Gamma$ is countable and so $\rho(\Gamma)=0$.

Now let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint measurable subsets of $\Bbb R$. Then, $A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$ are disjoint measurable subsets of $C$. Note that $c(A \cap C)$ and $c(B \cap C)$ may not be disjoint, because $c$ (even restricted to $C$) is not injective, but $c(A \cap C) \cap c(B \cap C) \subseteq \Gamma$. So, $\rho(c(A \cap C) \cap c(B \cap C))=0$.
So we have
\begin{align*} 
\mu(A \cup B) & = \rho(c((A \cup B)\cap C)) =\\ 
& =  \rho(c((A\cap C) \cup ( B \cap C))) = \\ 
&=\rho(c(A\cap C) \cup c(B\cap C)) = \\
& = \rho(c(A\cap C)) + \rho(c(B\cap C)) - \rho(c(A\cap C) \cap c(B\cap C)) = \\
& = \rho(c(A\cap C)) + \rho(c(B\cap C)) = \\
& = \mu(A) + \mu(B)
\end{align*}

Now to prove that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive, it is enough  to prove that $\mu$ is continuous from below.

Suppose $\{A_i\}_i$ is a non-decreasing monotonic family of measurable subsets of $\Bbb R$. Then $\{A_i \cap C\}_i$ is a  non-decreasing monotonic family of measurable subsets of $C$. Then $\{c(A_i \cap C)\}_i$ is a  non-decreasing monotonic family of measurable subsets of $[0,1]$. So, wee have

\begin{align*} 
\mu \left (\bigcup_i A_i \right )& = \rho \left (c \left ( \left ( \bigcup_i A_i \right )\cap C \right ) \right ) = \\
&= \rho \left ( \bigcup_i c(A_i \cap C)   \right) = \\
&= \lim_i \rho(c(A_i \cap C)) = \\
& =  \lim_i \mu(A_i)
\end{align*}

So $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive.

It is immediate that $\mu(\Bbb R)= \rho(c(\Bbb R \cap C))=\rho(c(C))=\rho([0,1])=1$. So $\mu$ is a probability.  It is also immediate that if $A\cap C=\emptyset$ then $\mu(A)= \rho(c(A\cap C)) =\rho(c(\emptyset))=\rho(\emptyset) = 0$. So, a support of $\mu$ is $C$.